# Sort array until 3 elements are in order, and leave the rest as they are

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array until the first 3 elements are in the correct order and immediately return the resulting array.
For example if given the array

`const arr = [77, 9, 3, 5, 1]` would return `[1, 3, 5, 77, 9]`
I tried using the default `sort` method but I couldn't figure out how to stop it when 3 elements are in the correct order.

I've put numbers here for simplicity. The elements I need to sort are not numbers.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: _"I tried using the default `sort`..."_ - Then add that attempt and we can try to fix it.

Comment: In other words, you want to extract the 3 minimal values from an array?

Comment: How do you know that the _"first 3 elements"_ in any step of sorting are the same _"first 3 elements"_ when the sorting of the complete array would be finished? If we remove `5` from the example, would `1, 3, 77` still be "valid"?

Comment: May I ask you the reason for this sorting? It looks like we might be dealing with an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: I don't actually need to sort numbers, I just put numbers here for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well there are couple of ways you can do it, here is a simple solution.

```
arr = [77, 9, 3, 5, 1];
arr2 =[];
arr2.push(...arr.splice(arr.indexOf(Math.min(...arr)), 1));
arr2.push(...arr.splice(arr.indexOf(Math.min(...arr)), 1));
arr2.push(...arr.splice(arr.indexOf(Math.min(...arr)), 1));
result = [...arr2,...arr];
```

this will take 3 smallest element from arr and push it to second array and then you can combine 2 arrays to get your desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've used a for loop instead of having the same line three times, and adapted it to fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since we only need the first three items to be sorted, **we can use a backwards bubble sort** algo.

- After three passes the first three items will always be the smallest.

**Here's what it looks like in our case:**

```js
let arr = [77, 9, 3, 5, 1];

// Using a bubble sort starting from the back,
// we know that after 3 passes the first three items will be sorted

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = arr.length - 1; j !== 0; j--) {
        let current = arr[j];
        let behind = arr[j - 1];

        if (current < behind) {
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
            arr[j - 1] = current;
        }
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```

[More on bubble sort.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/)